# How to add a metabox in edit category admin wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories, meta-boxes

I am trying but if I succeed using `add_meta_box()`
I have the following code:

```
function myplugin2_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'category', 'page' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'cat',
            __( 'Scroll infinito', 'myplugin2_textdomain' ),
            'myplugin2_meta_box_callback',
            $screen,
            'side'
        );
    }

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin2_add_meta_box', 2 );
function myplugin2_meta_box_callback(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  
 ?>

  <label>Activar</label>
 
  <?php

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code. Hopefully, work it.

```
<?php

function wp_category_fields($term) {
    
    $short_description = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'short_description', true);
    $color_code = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'color_code', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="term_fields[short_description]"><?php _e('Short description'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <textarea class="large-text" cols="50" rows="5" id="term_fields[short_description]" name="term_fields[short_description]"><?php echo esc_textarea($short_description); ?></textarea><br/>
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter short description'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="term_fields[color_code]"><?php _e('Color code'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo esc_attr($color_code); ?>" id="term_fields[color_code]" name="term_fields[color_code]"><br/>
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter color hex code'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <?php
}

// Add the fields, using our callback function  
// if you have other taxonomy name, replace category with the name of your taxonomy. ex: book_add_form_fields, book_edit_form_fields
add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'wp_category_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'wp_category_fields', 10, 2);

function wp_save_category_fields($term_id) {
    if (!isset($_POST['term_fields'])) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['term_fields'] as $key => $value) {
        update_term_meta($term_id, $key, sanitize_text_field($value));
    }
}

// Save the fields values, using our callback function
// if you have other taxonomy name, replace category with the name of your taxonomy. ex: edited_book, create_book
add_action('edited_category', 'wp_save_category_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('create_category', 'wp_save_category_fields', 10, 2);
```

**show value by.**

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();
echo get_term_meta($id, 'color_code', true);
```